# How to remove REFERENCES from PostgreSQL table but save indexes for these columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgreql table with references to other tables. I need remove all references, but save its column. And the difficulty is that these columns have indexes

```
CREATE TABLE _read_status
(
    id uuid NOT NULL CONSTRAINT _read_status_pkey PRIMARY KEY,
    chat_id uuid NOT NULL CONSTRAINT _read_status_chat_fkey REFERENCES _chat (id),
    user_id text CONSTRAINT _read_status_user_info_pkey REFERENCES _user_info (user_id),
    company_id text,

    CONSTRAINT uk_chat_id_user_id UNIQUE (chat_id, user_id),
    CONSTRAINT uk_chat_id_company_id UNIQUE (chat_id, company_id)
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS _idx_chat_id_user_id ON _read_status (chat_id DESC, user_id);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS _idx_chat_id_company_id ON _read_status (chat_id DESC, company_id);
```

I need to turn it into a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE _read_status
(
    id uuid NOT NULL CONSTRAINT _read_status_pkey PRIMARY KEY,
    chat_id uuid NOT NULL,
    user_id text,
    company_id text,

    CONSTRAINT uk_chat_id_user_id UNIQUE (chat_id, user_id),
    CONSTRAINT uk_chat_id_company_id UNIQUE (chat_id, company_id)
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS _idx_chat_id_user_id ON _read_status (chat_id DESC, user_id);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS _idx_chat_id_company_id ON _read_status (chat_id DESC, company_id);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try these commands:

```
ALTER TABLE _read_status DROP CONSTRAINT _read_status_chat_fkey;

ALTER TABLE _read_status DROP CONSTRAINT _read_status_user_info_pkey;
```

Comment: best would be to show an working example https://dbfiddle.uk/Nm-7mY22